# How to do use only first column in 2 column report, having static text in other column?

Tags: jasper-reports, subreport

I want to create a report with two column detail band.

first  column is for my subreport and the second one for static data that will appear on every page when my  sub report over flow. what configuration should i to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oneway to achive this is to use the `<background>` band.

Set number of columns in your report to only 1 and then use half of the detail band for you subreport.

Add the `<background>` band and put on the other half your static data, at the positions you like.

If you have the problem of having other pages that should not have these static variables as background, you need to make the whole of this report as a subreport.

I have not passed much code, if you need code example of how to add background band let me know.

Have fun..